# Cucumber - Deleting Cache and Cookies

Tags: ruby, cucumber, selenium-webdriver, capybara

I am using Cucumber to perform automated tests. I am running two features during a run where in I enter my credentials to perform an action in the website. When second feature is executed I will have to re-enter the same credentials but the browser had already stored my credential previously making the script to actually skip/fail at this step. I have shared my script below. Please advice what can be the solution.

I tried deleting cookies but still the problem persists.

```
When /^I clear cookies$/ do
  browser = Capybara.current_session.driver.browser
  browser.manage.delete_all_cookies
end
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case, You need to reset your sessions which will allow you to re login again with out any issues!

in your code:

```
When /^I clear cookies$/ do
  Capybara.reset_sessions!
end
```

Accept my answer if it works for you!

Comment: What is the difference between "reset_session" and "reset_sessions"?

Answer (score 0):

Starting a new browser session guarantees a clean environment.  However, depending on your setup and test suite, it slow tests down too much, but you might want to try that.

Deleting cookies does not drop credentials if you logged in using HTTP basic auth.  If that is the case, there's no other generally applicable way than to restart browser.